# PHP function to remove the first sentence from a paragraph

Tags: php

I found very usefull the function to returne the first sentence from a paragraph.

refer: [Returning first sentence from variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554375/returning-first-sentence-from-variable-in-php/65481176#65481176)

I have product description in xml file and i want to get the first sentence for a title and the rest as a description.

Example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

With the refer, I get for title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

I want to get for description: Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

What is the function to remove the first sentence from a paragraph? (sentence variations end = '.?!')

Answer (score 1):

you can use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

```php
$paragraph = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam';

return explode('.', $paragraph)[1];  //here i want second index
```

This function return an array, So to get specific sentence specify index of sentence

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know to write functions, can you please help?

Comment: I find one function but i don't know how to include more symbols than '.', my descriptions has end at '.!'

Comment: function last_sentence($content) {
$pos = strrpos($content, '.');
$pos_two = strrpos($content, '.', $pos - strlen($content) - 1); 
if($pos_two === false) {  
 return $content;  
 }  
 else {  
 return substr($content, $pos_two+1);  
 }
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276055/how-to-get-the-last-sentence-from-chunk-of-text-in-php

Comment: So if you want to split string with multi delimiter you can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php function also you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955433/php-multiple-delimiters-in-explode